# Insert HABTM sequelize js

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Does anyone know what's the best way to insert a HABTM rule into the database using sequelize js?

My tables are **users** <-- **user_books** --> **books**. So Books can have multiple users and a user can have multiple books. Now if I want to insert a new book into the database I use:

```
User.find(query).complete(function(err,source){
      var data = {
        book: req.body.book,
      };
      Book
        .create(data)
});
```

This works well to insert a new book for an existing user. But the user_books table stays empty. Even though I created an UserBooks model:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted shows nothing about a UserBooks model?

You can do two things:

*Create the book and associate it with user:*

```
Book.create(data).then(function (book) {
  source.addBook(book)
});
```

or *In a single step:*

```
source.createBook(data).then(function (book) {

});
```

Have a look at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Associations